# Nodes running in archive mode cosumes different disk space?

Tags: go-ethereum, archive-node

I have 2 nodes, running in archive mode, both using `Geth/v1.1.2-c4f93121-20210825/linux-amd64/go1.15.14`. Both of them  has finished syncing with the network (I checked using eth.syncing and it returned false).

One of them is used as an rpc endpoint for another app, which triggers debug_traceBlockByNumber for every new block.

This node consumes 8.7 TB of disk space so far, while the other one (which is not used to serve debug_traceBlockByNumber call) uses only 1.6 TB.

Isn't the disk space usage should be similar?

Comment: That eth.syncing returns false doesn't means it has finished, it might be paused because there isn't enough peers. Check the latest block in each to be sure they are really synchronized.